# Unable to set task icon to custom icon stored in resource

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set a custom icon on the balloon pop ups of a NotifyIcon control within my Windows Forms project. My icon has been imported into the project Resources of the project and is named "rwc".

[image: Icon]

I change the icon based on the error message (eg, error icon on an error message, info icon on an information message, etc. For normal messages, I would like the custom application icon.

This is the code I currently have:

```
taskIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.rwc;
taskIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Minimised!";
taskIcon.BalloonTipText = "I'm down here!";
taskIcon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
```

Testing the application, I get no debug errors but the custom icon does not show. I've searched various threads and online resources but can't seem to find any suggestions to get this working. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Did you set **visibility** of *taskIcon* to **true** before showing it?

Answer (score 0):

First add properly icon to your application. It must be `.ico` extension. And set `NotifyIcon` like this.

```
 taskIcon.Icon = new Icon(this.Icon, 40, 40);
```

Or

```
Icon myIcon = new Icon("Resources/rwc.ico");
taskIcon.Icon = new Icon(myIcon, 40, 40)
```

Or

```
 taskIcon.Icon= new Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Resources/rwc.ico")).Stream);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've given the second batch of code a try and not really had any luck with it. Running the application causes it to error out because it's unable to find "C:\RWC\Resources\rwc.ico". I'd rather not have the icon separate file if possible, hence why I've imported it into the projects Resources.resx file.

Comment: this rwc is .ico? you sure it isnt a .png or other extension?

Comment: It's an *.ico file. 100%. Edit: Added screenshot to post.

Comment: taskIcon.Icon = new Icon(Properties.Resources.rwc, 40, 40); try this